# How to Bulk find and replace MySQL for post image url

Tags: mysql

after the website migration, I find there are some image URL for some posts are misplaced. suppose the image URL for the article should be in /2021/07/, however it became /2020/07, and the image dead 404. I have to replace the image URL manually from the Gutenberg editor. https://ibb.co/bggdX7V

If I want to do it with SQL Command, how should I do it in a safe way? is it correct to find all wp-content/uploads/2021/07/, replace as wp-content/uploads/2021/07/ from the wp_postmeta table?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://interconnectit.com/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) tool for the bulk updates.
but make sure to back up the database before using this tool.
link to git is [here](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB)